# latest 5 posts using switch_to_blog loop

Tags: multisite, get-posts, switch-to-blog

im sure i must be doing something wrong and would really appreciate a little help.

I am trying to loop through all of my Sub Dir "Multisite" blogs using switch_to_blog, below:

```
global $wpdb, $blog_id, $post;
    $blogs = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM wp_blogs ORDER BY blog_id" ) );
    foreach ($blogs as $blog){

        switch_to_blog($blog->blog_id);
        $globalquery = get_posts('numberposts=5&post_type=any');
        restore_current_blog();

    }
    array_merge($globalquery, $portfolio);
```

It does work (kinda), it moves to the next blog (id = 2) and is retrieving posts, but goes no further and does not retrieve the main blog posts (id = 1).

I am a self proclaimed php noob, but really enjoy learning and i think im doing quite well lol

Please if someone could help me out?

Regards
Rory

***UPDATE***
I am trying to create a loop that i can pass into an already declared query:

```
// create query the portfolio (pass it to $wp_query)
        $portfolio_query = new WP_Query( $portfolio );
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's retrieving the posts just fine, but you're not storing them anywhere.  Here's your code again, with line-by-line documentation:

```
// Set up global variables. Great
global $wpdb, $blog_id, $post;

// Get a list of blogs in your multisite network
$blog_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT blog_id FROM $wpdb->blogs" );

// Iterate through your list of blogs
foreach ($blog_ids  as $id){

    // Switch to the next blog in the loop.
    // This will start at $id == 1 because of your ORDER BY statement.
    switch_to_blog($id);

    // Get the 5 latest posts for the blog and store them in the $globalquery variable.
    $globalquery = get_posts('numberposts=5&post_type=any');

    // Switch back to the main blog
    restore_current_blog();
}

// Merge the results of $globalquery with a $portfolio array
array_merge($globalquery, $portfolio);
```

The trick is that, in every loop of your `foreach` statement, you're *overwriting* the contents of `$globalquery`.  It will only ever have a set of posts from the last blog in your network.

Instead, set up a container before your `foreach` and merge your `$globalquery` results into it:

```
$globalcontainer = array();
foreach ($blog_ids  as $id){

    switch_to_blog( $id );

    $globalquery = get_posts( 'numberposts=5&post_type=any' );

    $globalcontainer = array_merge( $globalcontainer, $globalquery );

    restore_current_blog();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i assume that i then need to merge both the '$globalcontainer' & '$portfolio' arrays? 

Looking at the code it does make sense and i thank you for helpin me on my learning path :)

Comment: Im not quite there yet lol.
Using var_dump i can infact see that i am retrieving posts.
Now the $portfolio query is this:

'// create query the portfolio (pass it to $wp_query)
   $portfolio_query = new WP_Query( $portfolio );'

I am somehow wanting to merge the '$globalquery' or '$globalcontainer' with the portfolio query.

So far i am having little luck, could you point me in the right direction? probably something silly like a global variable knowing me lol

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Please edit your question to add updates, progress, and code changes. It's easier to read code when it's up there rather than in a comment.

Comment: Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

To get Blog ids you can use:

```
$blogs = wp_get_sites ();
$blogs_id = array();
foreach ($blogs as $blog) {
    $blogs_id [] = $blog["blog_id"];
}
```

instead of:

```
global $wpdb, $blog_id, $post;
$blogs = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM wp_blogs ORDER BY blog_id" ) );
```